# "The Latest on" vs "The Latest in"

Tags: american-english

What is the proper usage of "The Latest", describing what the website is about?

As an example I've came across some websites/newspapers that are using "The Latest **on** Apple ", "The Latest **on** ISIS threat" , "The Latest **on** Donald Trump" and etc.
However, other websites/newspapers are using "The Latest **in** Beauty", "The Latest **in** Nutrition Related Research", "The Latest **in** science and technology news"  and etc.

Thank you

Comment: If you examine the examples that you provided, 'on' is used for people/organizations and concrete nouns while 'in' is used for ideas and abstract nouns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The latest on..." generally refers to the latest information about a specific topic. "The latest in..." refers to information that is in a large field of study. For example, "The latest in science" may refer to self-driving cars, since they are a part of science. "The latest in art" may be an interesting use of color. But you would be more likely to say "The latest on Barack Obama" since he's a specific topic.

There is overlap where you could choose either one, so this is just a general guideline.